# Find all values associated with certain value in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a signup form and am onto the confirmation email part. I want to find all values associated with one other value in a database.
Ex. I get the "key" that is in the URL, then want to find all the values associated with it. In my database there are 4 columns: STR (the key), USERNAME, PASSWORD, and EMAIL. If I get STR I want to get the username, password, and email that are in the same row as the key and then insert it into another table in the same database.

verify.php:

```
<?php
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $servername = "localhost";
    $user = 'usernamelol';
    $pass = 'passwordlol';
    $dbname = 'vibemcform';
    $str = $_GET['str'];
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    /* The variable query gets the "key" from the dont database. I want to compare that value with the other values associated with it. Ex. the variables in the same row as the key. */
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `dont` WHERE STR='".$key."'");


    /* Below is my attempt. Feel free to change whatever you want. */
    $sql = "SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL FROM dont";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (!$query) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $sqltwo = "INSERT INTO data (USERNAME, PASSWORD, EMAIL) VALUES ($row["USERNAME"], $row["PASSWORD"], $row["EMAIL"])";
            }
        }
    }


    echo 'Successfully verified your email!'; exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simpy use the `insert ... select` syntax?

```
insert into data(username, password, email) 
select username, password, email from dont where str = :key
```

You can run this query right ahead, and then check how many rows were affected:

- If no row was affected, then it means that the `select` did not bring a row back: so the `:key` was not found in the database
- If a row was affected, then the key was found *and* the executed row was inserted

Note that you should use parametrized queries so your code is safe from SQL injection (and more efficient as well); recommended reading [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716)?

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot :) I get this error however:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::exec() in C:\xampp\htdocs\vibemcform\verify.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vibemcform\verify.php on line 19`
Updated code: [link](https://sourceb.in/ef05902e9c)

Comment: @Xp10d3: this is most likely not related to the query itself. You might want to read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/10676716) for how to debug php code.

Comment: Okay. I think I fixed it :) Thanks so much.

Comment: @GMB Sorry for the downvote yesterday (yeah, that was me :( ), I meant to upvote it and couldn't retract on time since I had to leave. I since edited to remove it and added the deserved upvoted. I also fixed a few typos :) Sorry about that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: no pb at all! Thanks for telling, and thanks for the typo fixes too.